# Frage zur Artikulation und Aussprache

Tags: pronunciation

Sehr oft hört man eine wirklich abgeschliffene Artikulation im Alltagsgespräch, besonders bei jüngeren Sprechern und vorwiegend im Norden. Ich als Nichtmuttersprachler finde es richtig schwierig dieser Aussprache zu folgen und mache wahrscheinlich ab und zu ein dummes Gesicht, wenn ich es nicht verstehe.

Beispiel: Bei 25:47 hört man dies was ich meine
https://youtu.be/NxJOSp8JLdo?t=1540

Meine Fragen dazu sind:

Haben auch manche Muttersprachler damit Schwierigkeiten, oder ist dies nur eine Gewohnheitssache?
Hat diese Aussprache eine Bezeichnung oder einen Namen?

Comment: *Genuschel* ist denke ich für jeden schwer verständlich. Aber zwischen Schweden und Norddeutschen sind ja noch die Dänen dazwischen und die nuscheln ja angeblich noch schlimmer.

Comment: Hast du Beispiele für die abgeschliffene Artikulation oder ist wirklich *nuscheln* gemeint?

Comment: @Janka, die Dänen sind auch nicht für Schweden soo einfach zu verstehen. Ich habe ein Beispiel jetzt in der Frage mitgenommen.

Comment: Hinweis: Du kannst Stellen in Youtube-Videos direkt verlinken, indem du Minute und Sekunde an den Link so dranhängst:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NxJOSp8JLdo&t=25m47s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ich bin aus Österreich, geboren und aufgewachsen in Graz, war 20 Jahre lang in Wien und lebe jetzt in St. Pölten. Ich bin geographisch also sehr weit weg von dem Traktorsammler aus dem Video, aber ich habe ihn auf Anhieb sehr gut verstanden.

### Stimmsitz

Mein Gesangslehrer würde sagen, dass der Sprecher seinen [Stimmsitz](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gesangsp%C3%A4dagogik#Stimmsitz) weit hinten hat. (Der Stimmsitz ist nicht nur in der Gesangspädagogik, sondern auch in der [Sprechtechnik](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprechtechnik) ein wichtiger Aspekt.) Damit ist genau das gemeint, was andere hier als *geknödelt* oder *knödelige Aussprache* bezeichnen. Aber ich halte das eher für eine individuelle Ausprägung, denn das hört man auch in Österreich recht häufig.

Der bereits verstorbene Schauspieler Theo Lingen, der ja in Hannover, also auch eher im Norden des deutschen Sprachraums, aufwuchs, ist ebenfalls ein Gegenbeispiel zu der These, im Norden würde mehr geknödelt als im Süden. Lingen hatte eine sehr nasale Aussprache. Gesangspädagogen würden sagen, Lingen habe seinen Stimmsitz weit vorne.

Aber im Großen und Ganzen kann man durchaus regionale Häufungen gewisser klanglicher Ausprägungen der Sprechstimme erkennen, was vor allem auf den wechselseitigen Einfluss der Sprecher untereinander zurückzuführen ist.

---

### Umgangssprache

Alles zuvor gesagte hat nur mit dem Klang der Stimme zu tun, und würde auch zutreffen, wenn der Sprecher Japanisch oder Suaheli sprechen würde. Eine ganz andere Charakteristik der gesprochenen Worte ist das, was sich niederschreiben lässt, also der Text. Hier ist zu erkennen, dass der Herr aus dem Video eher im Norden Deutschlands beheimatet ist, was sich an gewissen Verschleifungen (»wennma«) und Wörtern aus der Umgangssprache (»wat«) erkennen lässt, die aber im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum so gut bekannt sind (als Teil des passiven Wortschatzes), dass sie bei Muttersprachlern zu keinen Verständigungsproblemen führen.

---

### Addentum

**Deutsch als [plurizentrische Sprache](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurizentrische_Sprache)**

Der deutsche Sprachraum ist, was Wortschatz und Grammatik betrifft, geographisch sehr uneinheitlich. Die Vorfahren der heutigen Deutschsprecher waren Alemannen, Bayern, Franken, Thüringer, Sachsen und Friesen, und jeder dieser germanischen Stämme sprach eine etwas andere voralthochdeutsche Sprache. Dazu gab es starke Einflüsse der Burgunder, Goten und Angeln, die bereits vor der Völkerwanderung ihre regionalen Spuren in der Sprache der Germanen hinterließen. (Ich spreche hier vom zweiten bis fünften Jahrhundert n. Chr.)

Das heutige [Standarddeutsch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standarddeutsch), dass Schüler heute in Deutschland, Österreich, der Schweiz, Liechtenstein, Norditalien (Südtirol), Luxemburg und Belgien in den Schulen lernen, und dass auch Menschen beigebracht wird, die Deutsch als Fremdsprache lernen, ist nur in wenigen Fällen tatsächlich die wirkliche Muttersprache eines Menschen. Denn noch immer, rund eineinhalb Jahrtausende nach dem Entstehen der deutschen Sprache, ist die wahre Muttersprache eines Deutschsprechers ein Dialekt, bzw. die Umgangssprache der jeweiligen Region.

Daher sprechen nur sehr wenige Muttersprachler wirklich genau die Sprache, die im Unterricht gelehrt wird. Die deutsche Standardsprache ist eine künstlich geschaffene Sprache, die zum Ziel hat, eine überregionale Kommunikation zu ermöglichen. (Die Friesen und Bayern des zweiten Jahrhunderts haben beide zwar Vorformen des heutigen Deutsch gesprochen, hatten aber sicherlich große Probleme einander zu verstehen wenn sie aufeinander getroffen sind.)

Eine Konsequenz daraus ist unter anderem, dass es nicht einmal einen einheitlichen Standard für die deutsche Sprache gibt. Es gibt drei Standards, je einen für Deutschland, Österreich und die Schweiz. Die anderen Länder, in denen Deutsch eine Amtssprache ist, übernehmen einen dieser drei Standards. (In Italien wird österreichisches Deutsch gelehrt, in Liechtenstein schweizerisches Deutsch, und in Belgien und Luxemburg deutsches Deutsch).

Diese drei Standards sind einander sehr ähnlich. Die Rechtschreibung ist sogar identisch, mit der Ausnahme, dass in der Schweiz statt *ß* immer *ss* geschrieben wird. Wer Deutsch als Fremdsprache lernt, muss sich zumindest in der Anfangsphase noch keine Gedanken über die Unterschiede machen. Wer übrigens im Ausland Deutsch lernt, lernt meist deutsches Deutsch, weil das die Varietät mit den meisten Sprechern ist (ca. 80 Millionen Menschen sprechen deutsches Deutsch, 8 Millionen österreichisches Deutsch und ca. 5 Millionen schweizerisches Deutsch).

Aber die Tatsache, dass es sogar zwischen den Standards Unterschiede gibt, ist ein Beleg dafür, dass die deutsche Sprache noch immer keine einheitliche Sprache ist. Daher wird jeder, der Deutsch als Fremdsprache lernt, früher oder später damit konfrontiert, dass man in der Schweiz sein Velo parkiert, in Österreich um Dreiviertel Acht ein Häferl Kaffee trinkt, und in Teilen Deutschlands Apfelsinen pellt.

Comment: +1 und als akzeptierte Antwort gemarkt, wegen der Stimmsitzerklärung und dass du den Traktormann ohne weiteres verstehst, obwohl ihr aus ganz verschiedene Regionen kommt. Das was du im Addendum aber schreibst wusste ich schon und ich habe auch nichts darüber gefragt.

Answer (score 1):

Der Mann ist ein bisschen außer Atem und brabbelt irgendwas, was ihm gerade in den Sinn kommt, als ihm der Reporter ein Mikro hinhält. Außerdem Hintergrundrauschen.

> Das'is von jahrelanger Sammlung. Wir restorieren Oldtimer. Und wenn'ma zwanzig Jahre Oldtimer restoriert hat, dann bleibt da so einiges über. Wir kaufen auch Scheunen auf, mit alten Ersatzteilen, weißtu, da findet sich immer wieder wat.

Das ist sogar eine ziemlich klare Aussprache, kein Genuschel. Udo Lindenberg oder Herbert Grönemeyer singen deutlich knödeliger.

Comment: Ja, was er sagt habe ich nach fünf-sechs Wiederholungen auch verstanden, aber das war nicht meine Frage.  Hat dieser Aussprache einen Namen? Knödelich? Du hast offenbar die Aussprache als  klar wahrgenommen, ich nicht. Ist diese Aussprache also für die meisten normalhörigen Muttersprachler gut verständlich?

Comment: @Beta: Ohne jemanden verärgern zu wollen - im Norden von Deutschland wird das bessere Hochdeutsch gesprochen. Bayern, Baden-Württemberg, Saarland, Sachsen usw. ist da benachteiligt. Aber nur sprachlich...

Comment: *Knödelig* heißt, dass jemand so spricht, als hätte er einen Knödel im Mund. Der Mann in dem Video spricht hochdeutsch ohne besondere Mundartworte. Das einzige, was ihn als Norddeutschen identifiziert ist das **au→o** in *restorieren*, das *weistu* und das *wat*. Er ist schwer verständlich, weil er etwas außer Atem ist, und weil er irgendwas vor sich hin brabbelt. Ich komme aus dem Grenzbereich zwischen Norddeutsch, Hessisch, Sächsisch – ich verstehe alle leidlich.

Answer (score 1):

> Hat diese Aussprache einen Namen?

Es macht ganz den Eindruck, als kämen hier zwei Phänomene zusammen:

1. eine regionale oder lokale [Dialektfärbung](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Dialektf%C3%A4rbung)
   "Wat" ist plattdeutsch für 'was'; dazu noch klangliche Eigenheiten.
2. eine leicht verwaschene oder [verschliffene](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/verschleifen) Aussprache 
   "wenn'ma" ist nicht genuschelt – es ist eine lokal durchaus übliche Verkürzung von 'wenn man'.

> Haben auch manche Muttersprachler damit Schwierigkeiten, oder ist dies nur eine Gewöhnungssache?

Beide Abweichungen vom höhersprachlichen Standard [vermindern](https://www.psycholinguistik.uni-muenchen.de/publ/stoer_sprach_zeit.html) die allgemeine Verständlichkeit. Diese Schwierigkeit ist jedoch gering für die unmittelbare Umgebung der gezeigten Sprecher, wo eine gewisse Gewöhnung an solche Sprachmuster zu erwarten ist. Die Schwierigkeiten nehmen für anders und in größerer Entfernung sozialisierte Hörer für gewöhnlich umso mehr zu. Dies hängt auch davon ab, wie stark und welche Eigenheiten dominieren. Leichte norddeutsche  Einschläge aus städtischem Umfeld sind vermutlich eher immer noch allgemeinverständlich als starke oberbayerische Färbungen aus abgelegenen Tälern.

Answer (score 0):

Die Teilnehmer an dem Traktortreffen und der Mann sind gerade etwas angespannt und in Hektik wegen der Vorbereitungen. Ab 25m47s wird etwas *genuschelt* aber noch gut verständlich gesprochen.

Die Teilnehmer kommen aus Ostfriesland und sprechen wahrscheinlich im normalen Leben noch viel Plattdeutsch. Das hört man auch ab 26m02s beim Vater des Mannes, der den Bekannten auf Platt begrüßt. Daher sehe ich eine Mischung aus Umgangssprache, Plattdeutsch und ein wenig Genuschel.

Es gibt in Ostfriesland regional sprachliche Einflüsse aus den Niederlanden z.B. `Fietse` = Fahrrad. Das findet sich sogar in Afrikaans in Südafrika.

Wenn platt gesprochen wird, haben auch viele Muttersprachler Schwierigkeiten.

Man sagt, die Hanseaten sprechen etwas ***knödelig*** - manchmal steht das aber auch für einen verärgerten Tonfall.